# R segment function with intervals

Tags: r, intervals, segments

I am having trouble understanding the segments function in base graphics in the context of my specific problem.

```
x <- 0:1000
y <- c(0, 40000, 80000)
```

Now I want to draw a plot with a line from 0 to 200 at y=0. Another line from 200 to 500 at y=40000 and the last line from 500 to 1000 at y=80000.

```
plot(x,y,type="n")
segments(0,0,200,40000,200,40000,500,8000,1000)
points(0,0,200,40000,200,40000,500,8000,1000)
points(0,0,200,40000,200,40000,500,8000,1000)
```

I believe it is wrong to define the exact segments here. If x where 0:3 I would knwo what to do. But what do I have to do in the case of intervals?

Comment: Well, for starters your `plot()` call doesn't work as `x` and `y` have different lengths. Second, you are passing multiple arguments to `segments` where, if you read `?segments` you'll note that it needs *vectors* of coordinates `x0` and `y0` and `x1` and `y1` which are the x and y coordinates to draw from and to respectively. Your `segments()` and `points()` calls are just plain wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to supply *vectors* of coordinates `x0` and `y0` and `x1` and `y1` which are the x and y coordinates to draw from and to respectively. Consider the following working example:

```
x <- seq(0, 1000, length = 200)
y <- seq(0, 80000, length = 200)
plot(x,y,type="n")

from.x <- c(0, 200, 500)
to.x   <- c(200, 500, 1000)
to.y   <- from.y <- c(0, 40000, 80000) # from and to y coords the same

segments(x0 = from.x, y0 = from.y, x1 = to.x, y1 = to.y)
```

This produces the following plot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A quick ggplot version:

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- seq(0, 1000, length = 200)
y <- seq(0, 80000, length = 200)
plot(x,y,type="n")

dta <- data.frame( x= from.x,y=from.y, xend=to.x, yend=to.y )
ggplot( dta, aes( x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend )) +
  geom_segment()+
  geom_point( shape=16, size=4 ) +
  geom_point( aes( x=xend, y=yend ), shape=1, size=4 )
```